# combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str - When displaying time - Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

When I try to use this code:

```
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M')
```

It gives me this error:

> "combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str".

**EDIT:**

I think my error is here:

```
naive_start = datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.min)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. What should I do differently?

Comment: This code is correct. The error must be in some other line. Give the more context.

Comment: `.strftime('%I:%M')` will return you string. Please check where your are passing `date` variable. If possible, give fulltraceback.

Comment: I just ran this in both python 2.7 and 3.4 and it's working fine. Not sure what is wrong with yours :s

Comment: @catavaran Do you see an error in this new code?

Comment: @Lafada Do you see an error in this new code?

Comment: @vishen Do you see an error in this new code?

Comment: @jph, have you got answer?

Comment: @jph, your another question answer as duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676110/display-12-hour-intervals-instead-of-24-hour-clock-style-django please check that duplicate answer. That might be solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The type of your `date` var is not `date/datetime` instance its a `string`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M')
>>> type(date)
<type 'str'>
```

And i guess you are trying to use it with `datetime.datetime.combine`

```
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time(10, 23))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str
```

While you should use `date/datetime` object.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.time(10, 23))
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23, 10, 23)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M')
> naive_start = datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.min)
> ```
>
> What should I do differently?

*"combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str".* error message suggests that you should *not* call `.strftime()` method that converts `datetime` object into string, drop it:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.now()
naive_start = datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.min)
```

where `naive_start` contains the start of the day (midnight) in the local time as a naive `datetime` object.

btw, if the code runs on a server in your django application then the local (server) timezone might not be very useful for your clients that might be in different timezones (from the server and each other). [Configure timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/).